# React component rerendering indefinitely when using Context with separate routes in Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have separate routes for some pages in my app, and I'm using Context to pass some props between 2 components. How the router part looks:

```js
const NonLandingPages = () => {
    return (
      <div className='w-full flex flex-wrap min-h-screen bg-dark bg-main-bg 3xl:bg-main-bg-xl text-white z-10'>
        <TrackedSitesProvider
          value={{
            trackedSites,
            setTrackedSites,
            updateTrackedSites
          }}
        >
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
            <Route path='/overview' component={OverviewPage} />
            <Route path='/add_new_site' component={AddNewSite} />
            <Route path='/registration_successful' component={RegistrationSuccessful} />
            <Route path='/confirm_registration/:token' component={ConfirmRegistration} />
            <Route path='/password_reset_successful' component={PasswordResetSuccessful} />
            <Route path='/delete_successful' component={DeleteSuccessful} />
            <Route exact path='/reset_password' component={ResetPassword} />
            <Route path='/reset_password/:token' component={ConfirmResetPassword} />
            <Route path='/delete_account' component={DeleteAccount} />
            <Route path='/send_review' component={SendReview} />
            <Route path='*' component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </TrackedSitesProvider>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <div className='app-basic-appearance'>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' >
            <LandingPage/>
          </Route>
          <Route component={NonLandingPages} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

Context code:

```js
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { TrackedSites } from '../types/';

interface ContextProps {
  trackedSites: TrackedSites,
  setTrackedSites: Function,
  updateTrackedSites: Function
}

export const TrackedSitesContext = createContext<ContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const TrackedSitesProvider = TrackedSitesContext.Provider;


export const useTrackedSites = (): ContextProps => {
  const context = useContext(TrackedSitesContext);

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useTrackedSites must be used within a TrackedSitesProvider');
  }

  return context;
};
```

Function which uses context:

```js
  const trackedSitesContext = useTrackedSites();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const token = await auth.checkTokenAndRefreshIfPossible();
      if (!token) {
        history.push('/login');
        return;
      }
      const data = await getExistingSites();
      if (data) {
        trackedSitesContext.setTrackedSites(data);
      }
      setWaitingForServerResponse(false);
    })();
  }, []);
```

For whatever reason, component which contains `useEffect` hook pictured above is constantly getting re-rendered. Problem disappears if I put all of my routes in 1 place, like this:

```js
      <TrackedSitesProvider
        value={{
          trackedSites,
          setTrackedSites,
          updateTrackedSites
        }}
      >
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
            <Route path='/overview' component={OverviewPage} />
            <Route path='/add_new_site' component={AddNewSite} />
            <Route path='/registration_successful' component={RegistrationSuccessful} />
            <Route path='/confirm_registration/:token' component={ConfirmRegistration} />
            <Route path='/password_reset_successful' component={PasswordResetSuccessful} />
            <Route path='/delete_successful' component={DeleteSuccessful} />
            <Route exact path='/reset_password' component={ResetPassword} />
            <Route path='/reset_password/:token' component={ConfirmResetPassword} />
            <Route path='/delete_account' component={DeleteAccount} />
            <Route path='/send_review' component={SendReview} />
            <Route path='*' component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </TrackedSitesProvider>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.